# Concatenate columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

How do you concatenate columns and add brackets?

Using Jupyter I have tried the following:

```
df['xxx (yyy)'] = df['xxx'] + ' (' + df['yyy'] + ')'
```

this results:

```
|XXXYYY| not |XXX (YYY)
```

Is there an escape character required?

Also is this warning applicable?

```
C:\Users\xxxxxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:461: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
self.obj[item] = s
```

Comment: Unless your `df.loc['xxx (yyy)']` is a new row, you should be doing `df.loc[:,'xxx (yyy)']` . If you use `df['xxx (yyy)']` directly it will throw you the warning you mentioned above. Other than that, the code for concatenation seems to be working for me if i do `df.loc[; 'column']=df['x']+' ('+df['y']+')'`

Comment: It creates the column but does and concatenates but does not show the brackets or space on Jupyter. I'll check and Excel output.

Comment: Excel is fine so it must be Jupyter.

Comment: Restart of kernel has resolved all issues.

Comment: No it doesnt show me the warning!

Comment: Okay thats great! :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to create an additional column, you should use `df['xxx (yyy)']` instead of `df.loc['xxx (yyy)']`, which creates an additional row.